# Saving and loading abstract data type to json file and reading from file in the game for Haskell

Tags: file, haskell, save, load, aeson

I am writing a game in Haskell in which I would like to save a list of an abstract data type to a text file in a JSON format and then reload that saved file. i.e read that file back into the list of the abstract data type, and then use that re-loaded list in my game as normal. I am quite new to Haskell and programming in general so I am a little unsure if this is possible in the first place.

I  believe I've set up my data type (Room) correctly. But I am unsure about FromJson and toJSON (is that syntax correct?).

Also, the way I am currently saving does not save the JSON file in the format I would like:

[{"reward":"treasure","enemy":"enemyOne","description":"this is a room"}]

whereas the description, enemy and reward should be the order.

(I also believe the data type Room should precede everything in a JSON file correct?).

Let me know if you need any more clarification. Thank you!

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    OverloadedStrings
  , DeriveGeneric
 #-}

module Game where

--import System.IO
import Text.Read
import Data.Char
import Prelude hiding (readFile, writeFile)

import Data.Aeson
import Data.Text as T hiding (length, tail)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as B hiding (putStrLn, length, tail, writeFile, readFile)
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BC hiding (putStrLn, length, tail)
import GHC.Generics


data Room = Room
   { description :: String
   , enemy :: String
   , reward :: String
   } deriving (Show, Generic)

-- is this syntax correct for parseJSON?
instance FromJSON Room where
   parseJSON (Object v) =  Room <$> v .: "description" <*> v .: "enemy" <*> v .: "reward" 

-- is this syntax correct for toJSON? 
instance ToJSON Room where
    toJSON (Room desc enem reward) = object ["description" .= desc, "enemy" .= enem, "reward" .= reward]



save lst =
    do
    writeFile "savegame.txt" (encode lst)
    return()

load =
   do
   lst <- readFile "savegame.txt"
   let new = decode lst
   start new 

start :: [Room] -> IO()
start lst =
 putStrLn("Starting the game, need to use the lst as a list of rooms")
```

These are the error messages I'm getting:

```
forStackOverflow.hs:46:14:
    No instance for (FromJSON a0) arising from a use of ‘decode’
    The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    Relevant bindings include
      new :: Maybe a0 (bound at forStackOverflow.hs:46:8)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance FromJSON DotNetTime
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.5.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      instance FromJSON Value
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.5.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      instance FromJSON a => FromJSON (Control.Applicative.Const a b)
        -- Defined in ‘aeson-1.4.5.0:Data.Aeson.Types.FromJSON’
      ...plus 89 others
    In the expression: decode lst
    In an equation for ‘new’: new = decode lst
    In the expression:
      do { lst <- readFile "savegame.txt";
           let new = decode lst;
           start new }

forStackOverflow.hs:47:10:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘[Room]’ with actual type ‘Maybe a0’
    Relevant bindings include
      new :: Maybe a0 (bound at forStackOverflow.hs:46:8)
    In the first argument of ‘start’, namely ‘new’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: start new
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `decode` from `Data.Aeson`, as is clear from [its documentation](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.10/aeson-1.4.5.0/Data-Aeson.html#v:decode), returns not the target type (whichever type you're trying to decode), but the target type wrapped in `Maybe`. In your case, this would be `Maybe [Room]`, not just `[Room]`.

This reflects the fact that decoding might fail (i.e. incorrect format or whatever), in which case the function returns `Nothing`.

This is what the compiler is telling you when it says "*Relevant bindings include: new :: Maybe a0*" - it says that the variable `new` has been inferred to have type `Maybe a0`, where `a0` is some not yet known type.

It then goes on to tell you that it can't pass a `Maybe a0` as argument to `start`, because `start` expects the argument of type `[Room]`: "*Couldn't match expected type [Room] with actual type 'Maybe a0' ... in the first argument of 'start'*"

To fix this, you need to handle the possibility of `decode` returning `Nothing`, and if it returns `Just`, pass the contents of it to `start`. Something like this:

```
load =
   do
   lst <- readFile "savegame.txt"
   let new = decode lst
   case new of
      Nothing -> 
         error "Incorrect file format"
      Just n ->
         start n
```

(note that calling `error` is not a good way to handle an unexpected condition; I only used it as an example)